# How to share common quiz data generated by one player to all other in real time matches using GameKit and avoid staring by all the players?

Tags: ios, objective-c, multiplayer, gamekit, gkmatchmaker

I am developing a quiz with real time matches using GameKit. How do I know who initiated the match as matching happening real time at both players' side.The problem is that if one of the players generates some random question and same question will be shared among all the players. I want to avoid sharing of questions from all the players. Any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Try making a class system. At the beginning of a match, have each player generate a random number. The highest random number will be classified as the "Sender". Rarely there will be a tie - In this case, simply resend the random number. Then, you can check if the device playing is marked "Sender" and then send the random quiz question.